# Is it possible to have a SQL database with Excel files as "data source"?

Tags: sql, vb.net, excel

Is it possible to make some kind of link from SQL to Excel making the Excel documents the true datasource? I don't want any data to be stored in SQL, all data editing will be done in the Excel sheets.

I know this is far from optimal but I don't have a choice, the data needs to stay in Excel.

I know there is an option to do this kind of links in Access and there I can access the data from within VS but I would really prefer SQL.

Comment: Why do you need to use Excel?

Comment: Use this link to find some info on excel and sql linkage http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306397

Comment: Are you saying *SQL* (Structured Query Language), but you really mean *SQL Server* (the Microsoft RDBMS product) by that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's also possible to use the Jet driver directly from your application and skip out SQL server.

I know this isn't a proper answer to your question but another thought that may be useful :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set up excel as a linked server. You'll need to use a jet driver but this is only available on 32bit machines (Microsoft dropped their support a while back).  In other words, this is completely not scale-able and not recommended in most production environments.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to choose Excel as a datasource then you can connect to it using .Net Oledb provider.

Consider VB.Net example below to read rows on excel sheet:

```
  imports System.Data.OleDb

        dim connstr as string = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=d:\exceldb.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"""
            Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(connstr)
            conn.Open()
            Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", conn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    da.fill(dt)
    For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
     'do your thing
    next
    conn.close()
```

Regards

Comment: How would you do this with multiple Excel files? Could you do a join of workbooks from different files, for instance?